# my aap crash on ios 7 when clicking on back button

Tags: objective-c

```
-(IBAction)Back:(id)sender{

NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",
[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],
@"/Dtmf-star.wav"];

//declare a system sound id
SystemSoundID soundID;

//Get a URL for the sound file
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];

//Use audio sevices to create the sound
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);

//Use audio services to play the sound
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
[Buttonback setImage: nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];

int size = [PhoneUrl length];
if (size>0) {
    PhoneUrl = [PhoneUrl substringToIndex:size-1];
}
dspText.text = PhoneUrl;

}
```

this i have done..i am able to delete one digit but if there is more than one digit application get crash...
It is working fine in ios6.

Comment: [not enough context.](http://apaczai.elte.hu/~13akga/content/emclstcd.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you post almost the complete code, these kind of problems are really hard to solve for us. But it is propably a good idea to run the program in combination with a debug function monitoring the memory, since your problem most likely has something to do with that.

Comment: i have done it.in console (int size = [PhoneUrl length];) in this line i am getting a warning msg like EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,adress=6f).and it stop here nothing happen.but it happen when i click at button..

Comment: it works by mistake i was assigning dspText.text = PhoneUrl;because of dis it getting crash.